# List only updated information such as comments, status changes etc. in YouTrack

Tags: youtrack

I only want to see the report of updated information fields in a set of fields.

The common search feature of YouTrack lists issues that matches the search criteria. Is it possible to see only the fields that are updated similar to `History` of an issue?

Actually `History` doesn't show comments in an issue. If possible, I would like to see them in such an update report too.

I want to use this report in order to get a quick overview of all issues: who did what today.

Answer (score 0):

The option is not available at the moment. There is a feature request https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-2465 .
Commonly, you can always sort issues by updated. Unfortunately, this way doesn't provide you with the report- what was changed, but it allows you, at least, knowing what issues were updated.